# Append Line if Line Contains Character

Tags: java, if-statement, append, concatenation

I'm trying to write a program to read a text file and append a line in the text file, say, line B, to the previous line, line A, if line B contains the string " &". Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Inputs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\frencke\\workspace\\Testing Stuff\\Append Tetsing\\file3.txt");
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> num2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
                String delimiter = " &";
                for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
                    if(lines.get(i).contains(delimiter))
                        num.add(i);
                }
                for(int i=1; i<=lines.size()+1; i++)
                    if(num.get(i-1) != num.get(i)){
                        num2.add(num.get(i));
                        System.out.println(lines.get(num2.get(i)));
                }
            }
        scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>     at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>     at Inputs.main(Inputs.java:21)

on line 21,

```
if(num.get(i-1) != num.get(i)){
```

I think that it's because I'm subtracting 1 from i, but I'm not sure why that's an issue since I initialized i as 1 instead of 0 to avoid this.
Any help would be appreciated; I've tried the StringBuffer .append() method as well with no luck, but if you have a solution that works with that or some other means, that would be just dandy.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3) Please use code formatting for code, ***input/output*** & structured documents like HTML or XML.

Comment: You cannot simply start from another index in the array. Arrays always start from 0. You could use `i-1` in the other places to compensate for the offset.

Comment: BTW: if you are trying to get "i-1" which is 0 and "i" which is 1 in an array with only one position (or as it says size 1) acceding to position 0 is ok but the second access to position 1 will give you the outOfBoundsException.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I fixed the indent and quoted the error.

Comment: @KBorja, why does my array only have size 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, with the help of other questions on this site and some stuff on a few other sites. I basically re-did all of my code, but here it is:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AppendIfFromFileScanner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\frencke\\workspace\\Testing Stuff\\Append Tetsing\\file3.txt");
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String delimiter = ".*\\s+&.*";
    try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("file4.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scanner.nextLine());}
for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++){
    for(String s=null; i<lines.size(); i++){
        s = lines.get(i);
        if(!s.matches(delimiter))
        out.write("\r\n" + s);
        else if(s.matches(delimiter))
        out.write(s);}
}
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
}out.close();
}catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the num.get(i-1) but the num.get(i) which causes the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Also your for-loop can be rewritten as:

```
for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
      if(num.get(i) != num.get(i+1)){
             num2.add(num.get(i+1));
             System.out.println(lines.get(num2.get(i)));
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand-- Why does num.get(i) cause this exception? And I changed my for loop to the one you suggested, but the exception doesn't change.

Comment: Oh, num.get(i) would be 1 (index of 2) when the size of lines is only 1. Okay. Now I just don't understand why the size of lines is only 1, since there are 5 lines in the text document that it's reading.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is generated due to `num.get(i)` and not `num.get(i-1)` as `num` contains `line.size()` elements and the loop is trying to access `lines.size()+1` element.

Comment: I rewrote my for loop (see Mathias Ghys's answer) so that there is no more lines.size()+1 content, and that didn't help.